# djongo with rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist gives create table error

Tags: python, mysql, django, mongodb, jwt

Currently I started a project to learn more of django + jwt and react.

Instead of using `sql` I used `mongodb` with `django` instead by using `djongo`.

It works pretty well setting things up, creating new model to test out.  So I started looking for `django + jwt` tutorials and come upon this tutorial

https://hackernoon.com/110percent-complete-jwt-authentication-with-django-and-react-2020-iejq34ta

Everything works fine up until the end about blacklisting tokens

I have my `settings.py` as suggested

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=14),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}
```

by making the `BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION` to `True`, I need to do a migration by `python manage.py migrate`

This is where the error happens, error I got is

`djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: CREATE TABLE "token_blacklist_blacklistedtoken" ("id" int32 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "blacklisted_at" date NOT NULL)`

I was poking around and couldn't get a solution so I tried changing db back using `mysql` instead, then the migration worked like a charm.

Does anyone know if I do keep using `mongodb` instead of `mysql`, is there a workaround for this migration and functionality to work?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Got a similar error ..if you figured this out, you might have an idea of what I should do. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73002707/12601926) out.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion just change USER_ID_FIELD to email or user_name and try to run the migration. It looks like Mongo is trying to create two-column with the name 'id'.

You can use SQL and no-SQL depending on the requirement. If your app needs both then use advanced Postgres in the project. JSONField has better solutions.